# animateLayoutChanges buggy when changing visibility to gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation, android-linearlayout

I have a list(container) with couple views I'd like to hide and show again when collapse/expand button is clicked.

No problem so far, now i want to animate hiding and showing of my nested views, i didn't want to complicate with animations and i went with default ones.

That is why i added android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to container layout, this works great when showing/expanding views, but looks terrible when hiding/collapsing views.

Is there any particular reason behind this behavior?

Code and example below:

[image]

Code

container layout

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/izdelek_podrponud_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                >

            </LinearLayout>
```

child view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_60px"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how i handle showing and hiding;

```
private void showViews(LinearLayout container, int visible, boolean show) {
    if (container.getChildCount() > visible) {
        for (int i = visible; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (show) {
                container.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                container.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't you find any answer for this yet? I have the same problem now